# how can I use multiple else statements?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to use a few `else` statements in my class method:

```
class Musician :
    def __initiate__(self,name, instrument, years_playing, practice_hours):
        self.name = name
        self.instrument =instrument
        self.years_playing = years_playing
        self.practice_hours = practice_hours
        # self.level = int(self.practice_hours*self.years_playing)

    def level(self):
        if self.practice_hours <= 1 and self.years_playing <=1:
            print (self.name,'is a beginner')
        else:
            self.practice_hours <=2 and self.years_playing <=2
            print (self.name,'is an intermediate')
        else:
            self.practice_hours <= 3 and self.years_playing <=3
            return (self.name, 'is an expert')  

player_1 = Musician('Don', 'guitar', 1,3)       

player_1.level()
```

Comment: I tried to clarify your title, but I obviously had to guess what you really meant. Please feel invited to clarify further by editing.

Answer (score 2):

There are many things wrong with your code. The actual question you have seems to be about using `elif` where you tried to use `else`; the general structure is

```
if condition:
    something should happen
elif other_codition:
    things which should be done in this case
elif third_condition:
    other things
else:
    unconditionally do this if none of the conditions above were true
```

where all the branches after the first are optional.

You are mixing `print` with `return`, and I'm guessing you meant `__init__`. Here's an attempt to fix the code.

```
class Musician:
    def __init__(self, name, instrument, years_playing, practice_hours):
        self.name = name
        self.instrument =instrument
        self.years_playing = years_playing
        self.practice_hours = practice_hours
        # self.level = int(self.practice_hours*self.years_playing)

    def level(self):
        if self.practice_hours <= 1 and self.years_playing <= 1:
            return "beginner"
        elif self.practice_hours <= 2 and self.years_playing <= 2:
            return "intermediate"
        elif self.practice_hours <= 3 and self.years_playing <= 3:
            return "expert"

player_1 = Musician('Don', 'guitar', 1, 3)       

lvl = player_1.level()
print(f"the level of {player_1.name} is {lvl}")
```

`__init__` is a reserved name for the method which gets invoked when you create a new instance; you can't use a different name and hope for it to be invoked under the shme circumstances.

The `level` function will still return `None` if none of its conditions are true, but how to fix that depends on criteria I can't know. Perhaps a better design would be to check for "expert" or "intermediate" and then otherwise always return "beginner" if neither of those are true.

```
    def level(self):
        if self.practice_hours > 2 and self.years_playing > 2:
            return "expert"
        elif self.practice_hours > 1 and self.years_playing > 1:
            return "intermediate"
        # else
        return "beginner"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use bisect to achieve the same, without using if

```
import bisect

def level(self):

    level_dict = {0 : 'is a beginner', 1 : 'is an intermediate', 2 : 'is an expert'}
    grade_ranges = [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3)]
    points, grade = zip(*grade_ranges)
    return self.name + level_dict[bisect.bisect(points, self.practice_hours)-1]
```

Comment: Very clever use of `bisect`.